# Expression Blend 3, solution not supported

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I'm trying to open a silverlight 4 application solution in Expression Blend 3.

However, Blend says that the solution is not supported.

Is there something I'm missing?

I'm following an example in the book Microsoft Silverlight 4 Business Application Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Blend 4 to open projects written for Silverlight 4.  The solution and project file formats differ.  Blend 4 is currently in RC state, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=88484825-1B3C-4E8C-8B14-B05D025E1541&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thank you Anthony. The book does not specify which version of Blend is needed, and I did not know that Blend 4 had a RC.